# Flex ItemRenderer not passing mouseover to parent

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, itemrenderer, advanceddatagrid

In an AdvancedDataGrid using an MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer, mouseover was not being  passed on to the AdvancedDataGrid.
After days of struggle, I wanted to share this:
In your data setter, assign super.data with the new value for mouse events to be bubbled (?!)

Example (doesn't work)

```
        override public function set data( value:Object):void {             
            var latency:Number = value[ ( this.listData as DataGridListData).dataField] as Number;

            // Do cool stuff
```

Example (works)

```
        override public function set data( value:Object):void {             
            var latency:Number = value[ ( this.listData as DataGridListData).dataField] as Number;
            super.data = value;

            // Do cool stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example above works. Hope it can save you the time it took me to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

just declare super.data = value before var latency......

```
 override public function set data( value:Object):void {  
        super.data = value;           
        var latency:Number = value[ ( this.listData as DataGridListData).dataField] as Number;
```

Comment: For clarity, it works both ways. My point was if you assign super.data then mouseevents just work.